# JavaFX ListView Row Coloring

Tags: listview, javafx-2, javafx

I have a LisView with a Cell Factory set. The cell factory changes the text color based on some flags for each row (black, red, green, blue, etc.)

When I select a row I want to change the color of the text to always be WHITE regardless of the original color of the text. This is because some of the text colors (such as red and blue ) don't look good with the default -fx-selection-bar color.

I added the following CSS snippet to my list view.

```
.list-view:focused .list-cell:filled:focused:selected 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-selection-bar;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-background: -fx-accent;
-fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

It works fine, but it doesn't return the text to it's original color when the selection is changed from one row to another.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: In CSS snippet, I cannot see the definition of WHITE. Did you change the `-fx-selection-bar-text` in somewhere else, in `.root` for example?

Comment: There was a bug in one version of JavaFX where this happened, the workaround was to specify the font CSS for the unselected state to black or whatever you are using.  First step might be to update your JDK if possible.

Comment: @Uluk Biy - thanks - It is supposed to be "white" -- I made the correction in my question above.

Comment: @Andy Till - I'm think I'm using the latest JDK 7 - I will verify.  I think the problem with using CSS to set the unselected state - is that CSS won't remember the previous color of the row.  Each original row might be blue, red, green, etc.  When the row is selected, the above CSS snippet successfully turns the textFill to white, when it is unselected how can I turn it back to the original color it was?

Comment: The bug was to do with inherited CSS not being found when state was changed, I'm afraid I have forgotten the bug number.

Comment: Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for this?  I'd like to see the cell factory code you use and verify if it is a bug or user error.